# How do I compare frequency data of more than two groups?

Tags: dataset, frequency

I am comparing the frequencies of a disease presenting in particular season.
The expected proportion would be 0.25 and the observed frequencies for spring, summer, autumn, and winter were 7, 9, 11, and 16 respectively (total n=43).

Could you tell me if what I have done is correct?

When I ran a Kolmogorov-Smirnov goodness-of-fit test the p value was 0.207, so not a significant deviation from what would be expected.
However, I wanted to specifically see if the disease was more likely to present in Winter so I performed a binomial test essentially 16/43 vs 1/4. The binomial probability in this case was 0.026.  I'm not sure if this was the correct use of this test?

Thanks for your help with this.

Comment: 1. How does this problem arise? 2. How did you choose to test winter? On the basis that 16 was highest (/furthest from expected)?